# Strlen causes segfault

Tags: c

I have problem with understanding `strlen` and/or `memcpy`. 
This is the snippet:

```
char * restP;
char * str;
//this returns a pointer 
restP = strrstr (input_buffer, "pointer");
//this prints this pointer
printf("%p\n", restP);

str = malloc( 50000);

//this is wrong, restP is a pointer to a sring; i can print it with printf("%s", restP); it just a part of input_buffer

memcpy(restP, str, strlen(restP)-1 );
```

strlen(restP) gives me an error - `segmentation fault.` 
Maybe someone could give me a clue what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `strlen` and not the `memcpy`?

Comment: You have your first 2 memcpy arguments reversed

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for restP variable.

Comment: No need to allocate memory for restP : `strrstr()` returns a valid pointer, or NULL if the string wasn't found. The code should check for `restP` not to be NULL before using it in memcpy().

Comment: How is `input_buffer` declared, and what's been read into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your arguments to `memcpy` are the wrong way around. The first argument is the *destination*, the second argument is the *source*. It looks like you want to copy the contents of `restP` into `str`.

```
memcpy(str, restP, strlen(restP) + 1);
```

I've added one to the length of `restP` so that the null character is copied too (which isn't counted as part of `strlen`. You don't need to subtract one from `strlen` unless:

1. You know `str` is long enough and it is initialised to zero so that any appropriately sized string that is copied into it will be terminated by a null character.
2. You don't want to copy the last character of the source string.

Answer (score 8):

Strlen counts characters until it reaches the NUL ('\0') character. Make sure your string contains this character, else strlen will count over the array bounds, case when the segmentation fault appears. C provides no checking for array bounds.

Also, check if the pointer you pass is valid (i.e. it is not null).